# AngularJS app vs Ionic app: What do they have in common?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have just started learning Angular and Ionic, and I have been asking myself, what do they have in common, so I could share my code between the two applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS is a framework to developing web application using Javascript and Html, Ionic is a framework for developing hybrid apps, Ionic require Angularjs to work and get all features, as documentation say:

> Ionic currently requires AngularJS in order to work at its full potential. While you can still use the CSS portion of the framework, you'll miss out on powerful UI interactions, gestures, animations, and other things.

In simple words, Ionic extends Angular features and transform it in a framework for create mobile apps.

I hope this help you a bit.

Comment: It should also be noted that Ionic can be used to develop Progressive Web Apps (even Ionic 1 has support for Service Workers and Manifests), and is even simpler to use it for that than AngularJS (as the Ionic starters come with the Service Worker and Manifest ready).

Comment: @GabrielLovetro What do you mean? I can make my web app with ionic, in the end?

Comment: Yes and they have even made some advances on the Desktop area (namely, the responsive grid and the split pane) recently. If you want to know how the PWA would work, just follow this [link](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/).

Comment: That's really Great!!